# How to find parent directory in PHP?

Tags: php, directory, parent

I have this code in HTML that works fine:

```
<link href="/mywebsite/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

However, this code in PHP does not:

```
require('/mywebsite/db.php');
```

Both db.php and styles.css are in the same directory. I can use:

```
require(dirname(__DIR__) . '/db.php');
```

But that seems rather ugly. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something obvious?

Yes. :)

```
require('/mywebsite/db.php');
```

`/` is the **system root** (`C:\` if you're a Windows guy). It's not relative to the URL your site is hosted at, it's relative to the system the site runs on. I'd guess your site is saved somewhere like `/users/aygosis/webroot/index.php`. `/mywebsite/db.php` probably does not exist on your system.

```
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'db.php'
```

is actually a good way to do this. You could also establish a base in a file that's available everywhere and make all includes relative to it:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

...

require ROOT . 'db.php';
```

Comment: Actually this is all on my system at the moment. I have Apache, MySQL, and PHP all installed (WIN). db.php and styles.css are both in the same directory on my computer in my htdocs folder.

Comment: @Aygo Yes, but when including CSS files in the browser it's relative to the URL. Including PHP files on the server is relative to the system. The two usually do not correspond.

Answer (score 1):

The common method here is to define some filesystem related constants, and then use them, i.e. in my little home-grown MVC framework, I define the following:

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    /**
     * Shorter Directory Separator Constant
     */
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    /**
     * Application Directory path Constant
     */
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
}
```

I then reference files like this:

```
require ROOT . DS . 'System' . DS . 'Library' . DS . 'compatibility.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini configuration file, add the location of your website files to the include_path.  This way it will search that directory when you call include() or require()